# How to achieve moving circle images in html canvas

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, clip

I am trying to draw several circular images on an html canvas.

For each of my pictures I do the following:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.closePath();
context.drawImage(images[i], ball.x - ball.radius + 2, ball.y - ball.radius + 2, ball.radius * 2 - 3, ball.radius * 2 - 3)
context.clip() // breaks
```

When I add `clip()` it simply breaks. Not sure what I am doing wrong, perhaps my understanding of clips is totally wrong.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/althea16/pen/GRXMmOw
See render method lines 80 - 84.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing the context.save()

working code was:

```
  context.save()
      context.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ball = balls[i];
      ball.x = ball.nextx;
      ball.y = ball.nexty;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.clip()
      context.closePath();
      context.drawImage(images[i], ball.x - ball.radius + 2, ball.y - ball.radius + 2, ball.radius * 2 - 3, ball.radius * 2 - 3)
```